# Prevent drop-down from closing in child React component when parent is refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I've done some research on this and the general consensus appears to be to utilize the `useMemo` and `memo` React components but I've not had any luck.

I have a parent React component (TypeScript) that also renders a custom child component that essentially creates an HTML `select` tag. That all works. However, the parent component is periodically refreshed using TanStack Query to display newly fetched information. This occurs about once a second. If the user is in the process of selecting an item in the drop-down list when this happens the drop-down list closes and has to be opened again. Needless to say it's rather annoying.

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, memo, useMemo } from "react";

function LogData(props: Props) {
  const [selectedUrl, setSelectedUrl] = useState<number>(0); // Tracks UI dropdown selection

  const theUrl = useMemo(
    () => ({ selectedUrl, setSelectedUrl }),
    [selectedUrl]
  );

  // This periodically executes the TanStack query which causes this component to rerender
  const { status, error, data, fetchStatus } = usePeriodicQuery(
    logUrl[selectedUrl],
    updateIntervalMs,
    "myQuery",
    isEnabled.current
  );

...additional code to parse the data...

  const MemoizedLogSelector = memo(LogSelector);

  return (
    <MemoizedLogSelector selectedUrlMemo={theUrl} />
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
    ...table data code...
    </TableContainer>
 );

function LogSelector(props: {
  selectedUrlMemo: {
    selectedUrl: number,
    setSelectedUrl: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>,
  };
}) {
  console.warn(">>> LogSelector is rendering..."); // This is printing on every parent rerender
  return (
    <TextSelectInput
      label="Log Select:"
      labelFontSize="body1"
      labelPlacement="row"
      onChange={(value: number) => props.selectedUrlMemo.setSelectedUrl(value)}
      onClear={() => {}}
      options={[
        {
          label: "Message1",
          value: 0,
        },
        {
          label: "Message2",
          value: 1,
        },
        {
          label: "Message3",
          value: 2,
        },
      ]}
      value={props.selectedUrlMemo.selectedUrl}
    />
  );
}
```

Is there something wrong with this code or another way to accomplish what I'm seeking?

Comment: `const MemoizedLogSelector = memo(LogSelector);` Move this outside of the `LogData` component.

Comment: Just to add to what @NicholasTower said. `memo` wraps your function component in a new function that handles the memoize logic, if you call it each render you create a new function with a new reference each render. This in turn causes react to see it as a completely new component each render causing it to unmount the old one and mount the new one, which is causing your drop down to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const MemoizedLogSelector = memo(LogSelector);
```

The problem is that this line of code is *inside* of LogData. As a result, every time logData renders, you create a brand new MemoizedLogSelector component. It may have the same functionality as the previous one, but it's a new function reference so it looks like a different component type to react. Thus react must unmount the old one and mount the new one, which resets any internal state.

Components must be defined only once, so move the line of code outside of LogData:

```
const MemoizedLogSelector = memo(LogSelector);

function LogData(props: Props) {
  // ...
  return (
    <MemoizedLogSelector selectedUrlMemo={theUrl} />
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
    ...table data code...
    </TableContainer>
 );
}
```

Comment: Aargh, I was SO close! This makes sense and solved the problem, thanks.